# PHP Printing 50 rows on per page

Tags: php

I am working on my PHP to fetch the data from mysql database to output them in the search results. I want to limit 50 rows in per page and if I have less than 50 rows like 21 rows in the page 2 then display the 21 rows.

I have got a problem with the limit, because when I tried to use `LIMIT 0, 50`, it will display total 71 rows which I only want to display no more than 50 in per page.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$search_mailbox = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM $folder WHERE from_email LIKE ? OR subject LIKE ? OR message LIKE ? ORDER BY received_date DESC LIMIT 0, 50");
    $search_mailbox->execute([$searchemail, $searchsubject, $searchmessage]);
```

And I have also tried this:

```
$search_mailbox = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM $folder WHERE from_email LIKE ? OR subject LIKE ? OR message LIKE ? ORDER BY received_date DESC LIMIT $offset, $limit");
$search_mailbox->execute([$searchemail, $searchsubject, $searchmessage]);
```

It will not limit the rows I want. It will still show the 71 rows.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

// Initialize the session
session_start();

//Connect to the database
require_once('config.php');

$searchemail = '%' . 'gmail.com' . '%';
$searchsubject = '%' . 'gmail.com' . '%';
$searchmessage = '%' . 'gmail.com' . '%';

$mailbox = $link->prepare("SHOW TABLES");
$mailbox->execute();
$folders = array();
$total = 0;
$total_rows = 0;
$i = 0;
        
while ($folder = $mailbox->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $folder = $folder[0];

    if (strpos($folder, 'users') !== false) {
        $folder = str_replace('users', '', $folder);
    }
    else
    {
        $folders[$i] = $folder;
    }
    $i++;
}

foreach($folders as $folder) {
    $search_mailbox = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM $folder WHERE from_email LIKE ? OR subject LIKE ? OR message LIKE ? ORDER BY received_date DESC LIMIT 0, 50");
    $search_mailbox->execute([$searchemail, $searchsubject, $searchmessage]);
    
    if ($search_mailbox->rowCount() > 0) {
        $total += $search_mailbox->rowCount();
    }
}

$page = 1;
$limit = 50;
//$per_page = 50;
//$pages = ceil($total / $per_page);

$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;


foreach($folders as $folder) {
    
    $search_mailbox = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM $folder WHERE from_email LIKE ? OR subject LIKE ? OR message LIKE ? ORDER BY received_date DESC LIMIT $offset, $limit);
    $search_mailbox->execute([$searchemail, $searchsubject, $searchmessage]);


    if ($search_mailbox->rowCount() > 0) {
        foreach($search_mailbox->fetchAll() as $k => $row) {
            $email_number = $row['id'];
            $search_from = $row['from_email'];
            $search_subject = $row['subject'];
            $total_rows++;
            echo $search_subject . '.........................' . $total_rows;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
                    
}

?>
```

I am unable to fetch the first 50 rows in the page 1 and I am also unable to fetch the 21 rows in the page 2.

What I am trying to achieve is when I am in page 1, I want to display the first 50 rows, then in the page 2 if I have another 50 rows then display the 50 rows, but if I have less than 50 rows like 21 rows then display the 21 rows.

Can you please show me an example how I can start with first 50 rows when I am in the page 1 then in page 2 display 21 rows to make in total 71 rows?

Thank you.

Comment: Tangentially related, but even though you've used parameterized queries, you're still open to SQL injection vulnerabilities as you've concatenated `$folder` directly into your query string.

Comment: @esqew Thank you for your advice, Im well aware about SQL injection so what change do I need to make? And how I can fix the limit on per page when I am searching for the folders?

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, don't concatenate `$folder` directly into your query string and instead include it as part of your query parameters.

Comment: Well I dont have the choice when I am searching for each table from the database. You didnt mentioned in what way I would use in a proper way and how i can fix the limit on per page?

Comment: So, how many rows do you actually get in the first page, and in the second page?

Comment: @tgarm I get 74 in the first page, however I have found out that it cant be controlled because i am using the loops. Any idea how i can limit 50 on per page using the loops?

Comment: Confirm your query first.  The `LIMIT` directive should work.  Run your query directly on the database (you cold use PHPMyAdmin).

Comment: @Nic3500 Im using mysql and im also using LIMIT so it doesn't work. The reason for this is because I am using the folder tables under the loops. Are there any other way to solve it?